# What to do after interrupting Shemoneh 'Esreh

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, hefsek-interruption

What are you supposed to do after interrupting Shemoneh 'Esreh? Do you start over? Continue where you left off?

Assume that the interruption was either permitted, or if it was forbidden it was accidental. Does it matter what the interruption was for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 104:5–6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=263) reads:

> If he paused [even silently —*MB*] [amid of *sh'mone esre* enough time] to finish the entire [*sh'mone esre*], he goes back to the start [of *sh'mone esre*]; otherwise, he goes back to the start of the *b'racha* he paused in. But if he stopped in [one of] the first three [*b'rachos*], he goes back to the start; [in one of] the last [three], he goes back to "*R'tze*". That which we said "if he paused to finish the entire", we assess the one reading.
>
> If he spoke during *sh'mone esre*, his rule regarding going back is like the rule for the interruptions mentioned [above].

*MB* qualifies this extensively, by limiting the reasons for pauses to which this *halacha* applies, by limiting the minimum length of a pause to which it applies, by limiting where the pause to which it applies was made, and so on. He cites a number of *machlokos* in these regards, so consult your rabbi for guidance.