# Noticing the chazzan's mistake while davening

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, hefsek-interruption, chazarat-hashatz

If you are still davening but you notice that the chazzan made a mistake (yes/no mashiv haruach during the wrong season, for example), and nobody else notices, can you interrupt your davening to correct him?  Is this a valid צורך התפלה?  It doesn't affect your personal davening per se, but it does affect the davening of the whole tzibbur in a more general sense.

I'd like an answer that covers several different parts of davening, but particularly shemoneh esrei and אלקי נצור since those are the most common places to be during chazarat hashatz.

Also, is the halacha different for parts that don't ruin shemoneh esrei if they're skipped, like זכרנו?

I admit the whole situation doesn't say much for the shul: the people who are supposed be paying attention to חזרת הש"ץ aren't, and the person who isn't supposed to pay attention is.

(Not from personal experience, fortunately.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17287/what-to-do-after-interrupting-shemoneh-esreh

Comment: Another POSSIBLE assumption ... Can we assume that the chazzan said it correctly in his own private Shemoneh Esreh (i.e. he didn't make a mistake). Also, we are now in an era where chazarat hashatz is just in keeping with an old minhag, and not because of its original reason which was b/c many people couldn't read the Amidah or there were few Siddurim around. Thus, perhaps, if no one corrects the chazan, it may not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shmoneh_Esrei#Interruptions) says:

> If you notice that someone made a mistake in Davening that would
>   require him to go back to the beginning, for example, you heard
>   someone miss Mashiv HaRuach (and Morid HaTal), one may signal with
>   one’s hands in order to get his attention, if that’s unsuccessful, one
>   should tell him after Davening. However, this leniency isn’t agreed
>   upon. [note 50]
>
> note 50 - Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach in Halichot Shlomo 20:6 rules
>   that one may signal to someone who made a mistake in Davening that
>   would cause him to repeat Shemonah Esrei. This is also the opinion of
>   Dvar Meshulam (pg 120) based on Igrot Moshe 4:16 (below). However, Rav
>   Elyashiv (quoted in Peninei Tefillah pg 85-6) holds that it’s
>   forbidden to signal to someone else because his mistake has nothing to
>   do with your davening unless the other person’s mistake bothers his
>   Davening. [From Sh”t Igrot Moshe (4:16 pg 28) who writes that in a
>   case where there was an announcement of the incorrect page number for
>   congregants who wouldn’t know any better that one may in Shaat
>   HaDachak announce the correct page number between Brachot in Shemonah
>   Esrei because the Tzorech Tefillah of others is like the Tzorech
>   Tefillah of oneself, it seems that Rav Moshe would agree to Rabbi
>   Shlomo Zalman.]

While this seems to speak about an individual's private  Shemonah Esrei, I suggest the principle can be extended to the Chazzan's repetition when he made an error for which he would have to repeat his  repetition to get it right or where the error bothers your davenning.

I have seen my Rav (still in his private Shemonah Esrei) gesture to the Chazzan under such circumstances. (*Shame on me for not doing it first.*)

Please note that [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chazarat_HaShatz) does require the Chazzan to repeat his repetition if he made a critical error:

> If the Shaliach Tzibbur makes a mistake in Chazara and forgets to say
>   an addition has the same halacha as in individual who forgets that
>   addition (with one exception).

Comment: Thanks!  I think you're right that Rav Moshe and Rav Shlomo Zalman would say the same in this case.  It's not entirely obvious that Rav Elyashiv would be machmir here, since chazarat hashatz is like an extension of everyone's individual shemoneh esrei.